# Why when trying to assign to a variant, an array for some non-IDispatch-exposing object type, is the array pointer assigned instead?

Tags: arrays, vba, com, ole-automation, iunknown

### Summary

After declaring an array for some object type where the type doesn't use an interface that *[derives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/midl/interface)* from [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/component-object-model--com--portal)'s [`IDispatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch) interface (& so isn't properly set-up to enable [OLE] [Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/_automat/)'s late-binding technology), trying to assign the array to a [`Variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/variant-data-type) variable doesn't work according to my expectations.

Specifically, what appears to happen is that an integral [pointer](http://www.samsvb.co.uk/index.php?page=lesson&les=Lesson%2030) to the array is assigned to the `Variant` variable, instead of a copy of the array.

Can anyone explain such behaviour? Is it standard behaviour of the VBA 7.1 language? <sup>[EDIT-A1]</sup> Is it that VBA's `Variant` type can't handle such arrays? <sup>[EDIT-A2]</sup>

<sup>[EDIT-A1] - ***Currently (4/6/19), it's looking like it's a bug.***</sup>
<sup>[EDIT-A2] - ***No, as the internal procedure parameters for `ByRef` `Variant` arguments can properly point to such arrays, if such arrays are passed as the values for such arguments.***</sup>

---

### Background

*More details on what appears to be happening*

After inspecting various memory addresses & pointers, what appears to be happening is that when assigning such arrays to `Variant` variables, the [`Long`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/long-data-type) (or [`LongPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longptr-data-type)) pointers to the *'VB safe array pointers'* of the arrays, are instead being assigned. This is contrary to the array-copying behaviour documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/2ae5553a-6515-4967-9b91-e06b527b137f) in the VBA language specification as being expected behaviour. I deduced such pointer assignment was taking place after reviewing VB6 documentation on VB arrays & their memory layout, stored [here](https://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/algorithms/article.php/c7495/How-Visual-Basic-6-Stores-Data.htm).

*My research into whether issue has been previously documented*

I've searched the internet, the [Office VBA Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/overview/) documentation, & the [VBA language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/) to see whether this problem has been documented by anyone else. The only place I've found where this problem may have already been partly documented is in a Stack Overflow answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726883/on-windows-with-a-c-sharp-authored-com-server-can-one-return-a-safearray-both/38728862#38728862). Unfortunately, the post doesn't say much about the problem.

*Specific array types that I have tested this issue with*

I have experienced this issue with arrays of the following object types that use interfaces not *deriving* from `IDispatch`:

- `stdole.IUnknown` <sup>*</sup>
- `stdole.IFont`
- `mscoree.CorRuntimeHost` <sup>†</sup>
- `mscorlib.AppDomain` <sup>†</sup>
- `mscorlib.Type`

<sup>* From OLE Automation COM type library in `stdole2.tlb`.</sup>
<sup>† From COM type library for the [.NET framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/) v4.0.30319.</sup>

*More on what an object type that uses an interface not deriving from `IDispatch`, is*

Such object types are `vbDataObject` types. Unfortunately, the current VBA documentation on the `vbDataObject` constant is inaccurate. I'm in the process of updating the documentation, & you can see my updated definition for the constant [here](https://github.com/MarkFern/VBA-Docs/blob/MF-PATCH/vartype-constants.md/part_or_full_scrub/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/vartype-constants.md).

***[EDIT - COM specification link removed as it is no longer relevant.]***

*Regarding arrays of other object types*

Arrays of `vbObject` types (COM object types that support [OLE] Automation late-binding technology) appear to be assigned to `Variant` variables in a straight-forward & expected manner - [array is copied and directly assigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/2ae5553a-6515-4967-9b91-e06b527b137f).

*VBE used to crash when inspecting such arrays using a VBE watch*

A potentially related issue is to do with a bug that used to occur when a VBE [*watch expression*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/forms/add-a-watch-expression) was placed on an array of a type that used an interface not *deriving* from `IDispatch`. The bug used to cause the VBE to unexpectedly crash. This bug appears to have been fixed by Microsoft within the last month.

*Software versions*

```
  Software               | Version      
-------------------------+---------------
  VBA                    | 7.1 ‡
-------------------------+---------------
  Microsoft Excel        | 2016 §
-------------------------+---------------
  Microsoft Windows (OS) | 8.1 ¶
```

<sup>‡ Full text for version is "Retail 7.1.1088"—the latest version.</sup>
<sup>§ More specifically, the latest [version & build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date) (released on 3rd June 2019, version 1905, build 11629.20214), & also earlier build numbers 11629.20196 & 11601.20204 (first was released on 14th May 2019).</sup>

<sup>¶ `ver.exe` program prints ["Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver_(command)#Version_list).</sup>

### Code

#### [Reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex):

```vb
    Dim MyArray() As stdole.IUnknown ' Type from OLE Automation 
                                     ' COM type library in stdole2.tlb.
    Dim MyVariant As Variant
    MyVariant = MyArray
```

I expected `MyVariant` to store a copy of the `MyArray` array.

Instead, in the 32-bit version of VBA, `MyVariant` stores a `Long` value that appears to be a pointer to `MyArray`.

#### Debugging issue

Click [here](https://gist.github.com/MarkFern/b1b7e9974b454c69cbf4bdcea4bd712d)
for VBA code to assist in debugging issue.

Comment: Interestingly, if you pass `MyArray` into a routine that accepts `ByRef v As Variant`, the `TypeName(v)` inside it is correctly `Unknown()`. So you can have `public function CorrectlyAssign(ByRef v As Variant) As Variant : CorrectlyAssign = v : End Function` and do `MyVariant = CorrentlyAssign(MyArray)`.

Comment: Yet another array-to-pointer bug in VBA, I am being kept amused. (Other examples are https://stackoverflow.com/q/3375562/11683 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/183356/11683).

Comment: Hello @GSerg - thanks for these comments. It's looking as though it is a VBA bug that occurs in type conversions from `vbDataObject`-object arrays to `Variant` data whenever array copying is involved. In the case of the `ByRef` type conversion, no array copying is involved, so the type conversion appears to be working as expected - such behaviour is still odd because it differs from the `ByVal` type conversion, with the `ByVal` behaviour being even odder.

Comment: Have now sent feedback using Microsoft Excel _Feedback_ feature, to Microsoft regarding this issue. Have asked them to confirm whether it is a bug.

Comment: Good luck with that (honestly), although I personally haven't had any success with my bug reports.

Comment: You're playing a dangerous game with the VBA type system.  It has no support whatsoever for IUnknown interfaces, it expects all of them to be IDispatch.  It probably suffers an internal heart attack while trying to copy the array elements on a failing QueryInterface call and punts for returning the array pointer instead.  This isn't going to get fixed, you need to declare the array As Object.

Comment: Hello @HansPassant. Thanks for your feedback. I don't think you are quite right about VBA not providing any support for `IUnknown` interfaces. Some of the COM types for the .NET framework do not support `IDispatch` but still work pretty well. See [here](https://marc.info/?l=ms-dcom&m=103440425612266&w=2) for someone else's opinion on whether pre-.NET VB supports `IUnknown` interfaces.

Comment: Hmya, "Of course, you can't really "work" with it" is the relevant phrase.

Comment: I don't know why it happens but you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62416803/8488913) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55838668/8488913) to make the copy